# I have the program created, but when I run the program it does not end when i enter 'A', 'a' or 'E', 'e'

Tags: c++, loops, char

> 3.Develop an algorithm that keeps asking the user to enter a valid choice if the entered choice is not 'A' or 'E'

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char letter = 'k';

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter any character, enter A or E to exit: ";
        cin >> letter;
    } while ((letter != 'A' && letter != 'a') || (letter != 'E' && letter != 'e'));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: when pasting the code select your code and press CTL+K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while ((letter != 'A' && letter != 'a') || (letter != 'E' && letter != 'e'));` Should be `while ((letter != 'A' && letter != 'a') && (letter != 'E' && letter != 'e'));`

The way you had it, the only way it could be false is if both sides are true so if we entered `E` the left hand side would be true since `letter!=A && letter!=a`

Answer (score 0):

change while condition to:

```
while((((letter - 'A') % 32) * 25 % 99) > 1);
```

Cheers :)